# Double Activity window when using intent for achartengine graph

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, duplicates, achartengine

Development Environment: Eclipse 3.7.0
Developing: Android 3.2 application for Market Place
Using: aChartEngine 0.7.0

I'm new to the development scene but have done a bit of coding in the past various languages, I've created the ZopaStats(on Marketplace) app, but I'm now trying to convert a text based stats page to be displayed in a bar graph using achartengine.
I can get the graph to display from an activity via another activity i.e.:

```
Intent achartIntent = new TemperatureChart().execute(this);
startActivity(achartIntent);
```

but this gives me an additional activity screen i.e.:

Main Screen -> 1st Activity (Original Text Stats View) -> 2nd Activity (Graph)

Therefore, with I hit back on the graph screen, I get the blank 1st activity screen.
I hope I'm making sense here.
So what I tried to do was launch the activity from the Main Screen (i.e. my Main class) e.g.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent achartIntent = new TemperatureChart().execute(this);
  startActivity(achartIntent);
  }
});
```

But eclipse gives me the following error in the code:

The method execute(Context) in the type TemperatureChart is not applicable for the arguments new (View.OnClickListener(){}}

I've tried letting Eclipse change the method but this then causes other problems, so I think what I'm really looking for (in a round about way) is to find out what the difference is when I can try to start the activity from another Activity class rather than starting it from the main class.

I apologise for the misuse of terms etc, as I say I'm new.  I've been looking at this for a few days now but the Intent and Activity documentation doesn't help me much so I just need a few pointers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, the new code is this:
N.B. My original class is called ZopaStats.class

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent achartIntent = new MarketZopaGraph().execute(ZopaStats.this);
  startActivity(achartIntent);
  }
});
```

This works great, only a single Activity windows, once again many thanks for the quick response, in record time ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `this` reference that you're passing to `execute()` is your annonymous inner subclass of OnClickListener. This is not a context object, which is what eclipse is complaining about.

Rather, you want to pass in the activity instance. Assuming the code snippet you posted lives in a class named `MyExampleActivity`, then you can use `MyExampleActivity.this` from inside the inner class to access the instance of the containing class. You should be able to pass that to `TemperatureChart.execute()`

There is no difference in starting an activity from the main activity or from any other activity. You just create an intent, and call startActivity on it.

Comment: Words cannot describe my gratitude ;)

Answer (score 0):

when we use achartengine to draw graph in includes it own activity...i.e.org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity..
when we press back it shows own activity which is used to show graph..to hide these activity call finish() method on onPause()  method.